# A Skolem model in Z3 should be unique, but is printing several (and repeated)

Tags: z3, smt, z3py, quantifiers

I am testing how similar are "assignment"-like models and "Skolem-function"-like models in Z3.

Thus, I proposed an experiment: I will create a formula for which the unique model is `y=2`; and try to "imitate" this formula so that the (unique) model is a Skolem function `f(x)=2`. I did this by using `ExistsForall` quantification for the `y=2` case and `ForallExists` quantification for the `f(x)=2` case.

Thus, I first performed the following (note that the `y` is existentially quantified from the top-level declaration):

```
from z3 import *

x,y = Ints('x y')

ct_0 = (x >= 2)
ct_1 = (y > 1)
ct_2 = (y <= x)

phi = ForAll([x], Implies(ct_0, And(ct_1,ct_2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())

for i in range(0, 5):
  if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()[y]
    print(m)
    s.add(And(y != m))
```

This code successfully prints out `y=2` as a unique model (no matter we asked for 5 more). Now, I tried the same for `f(x)=2` (note that there is no `y`):

```
skolem = Function('skolem', IntSort(), IntSort())

x = Int('x')

ct0 = (x >= 2)
ct1 = (skolem(x) > 1)
ct2 = (skolem(x) <= x)

phi1 = ForAll([x], Implies(ct0, And(ct1,ct2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi1)

for i in range(0, 5):
  if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m)
    s.add(skolem(x) != i)
```

This prints:

```
[skolem = [else -> 2]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, 1)]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, -1)]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, -1)]]
[x = 0, skolem = [else -> If(2 <= Var(0), 2, -1)]]
```

My question is: why is the `y=2` unique, whereas we get several Skolem functions? In Skolem functions, we get (and repeatedly) some functions in which the antecedent of `phi1` (i.e., `(x >= 2)`) is negated (e.g., `x=0`); but in models, we do not get stuff like `x=0 implies y=1`, we only get `y=2` because that is the unique model that does not depend on `x`. In the same way, `[skolem = [else -> 2]]` should be the unique "Skolem model" that does not depend on `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between these two queries. In the first one, you're looking for a single `y` that acts as the value that satisfies the property. And indeed `y == 2` is the only choice.

But when you have a skolem function, you have an infinite number of witnesses. The very first one is:

```
skolem(x) = 2
```

i.e., the function that maps everything to `2`. (You're internally equating this to the model `y=2` in the first problem, but that's misleading.)

But there are other functions too. Here's the second one:

```
skolem(x) = if 2 <= x then 2 else 1
```

You can convince yourself this is perfectly fine, since it does give you the skolem function that provides a valid value for `y` (i.e., 2), when the consequent matters. What it returns in the else case is immaterial. (i.e., when `x < 2`). And similarly, you can simply do different things when `x < 2`, giving you an infinite number of skolem functions that work. (Of course, the difference is not interesting, but different nonetheless.)

What you really are trying to say, I guess, is there's nothing "else" that's interesting. Unfortunately that's harder to automate, since it's hard to get a Python function back from a z3 model. But you can do it manually:

```py
from z3 import *

skolem = Function('skolem', IntSort(), IntSort())

x = Int('x')

ct0 = (x >= 2)
ct1 = (skolem(x) > 1)
ct2 = (skolem(x) <= x)

phi1 = ForAll([x], Implies(ct0, And(ct1,ct2)))

s = Solver()
s.add(phi1)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())

# The above gives you the model [else -> 2], i.e., the function that maps everything to 2.
# Let's add a constraint that says we want something "different" in the interesting case of "x >= 2":
s.add(ForAll([x], Implies(x >= 2, skolem(x) != 2)))
print(s.check())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[skolem = [else -> 2]]
unsat
```

which attests to the uniqueness of the skolem-function in the "interesting" case.

Comment: Perfect answer: I exactly wanted: "the unique skolem-function in the 'interesting' case". Thanks a lot! I understand these kind of conditions are harder to formalise and have to be "human-written".